# Mutable primitive as generic parameter

Tags: java, performance, generics

In my application I'll have array of about 100k Cells. This array will be updated with high frequency, therefor performance is crucial. Cell is container for a value of some type, mostly integer or floating, but there are scenarios where 2 or more ints are used, so best option is to make this class generic. I'd like to prevent copies and creating a lot of new objects at each update. I thought that objects should be Mutable, but making

```
 Cell<T implements Mutable<T>>
```

where

```
Mutable<T>
```

has method

```
void set(T value)
```

doesn't get me anywhere, set(T) will make a copy of parameter. Do you have any ideas how to make it possible? Is preventing copies even worthwhile?

Comment: Post some code demonstrating unexpected behavior.

Comment: @shmosel In set I must use assignment. T must be an object. Old value will  be discarded and left for GC to collect. I'll have possibly 100k new objects created every update and 100k old left for collection. I'm afraid that it'll hit performance.

Comment: None of that addresses my comment.

Comment: `Cell<T implements Mutable<T>>` is invalid syntax and makes little sense as it implies you want to store a `Mutable` inside your `Mutable`.

Comment: For a "performance is crucial" question, this is all extremely vague. What kind of performance? What are your targets, and are you at the second, millis, or microsecond level? What kind of data is this? Updated how and by what? And presented to a user how (or at all)? All this business about classes being generic and making copies etc. seems to be putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Are all the cells in your array of the same type?

Comment: @shmosel They are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what your code looks like, but if you're trying to make a mutable primitive wrapper for performance, it shouldn't be generic because that would cause its values to be autoboxed. You'll want something like this:

```
class Cell<T> {
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class IntWrapper {
    private int value;

    private int get() {
        return value;
    }

    private void set(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now we can update the value of a cell without any object construction or autoboxing:

```
class Main {
    private Cell<IntWrapper>[] cells;
    //...
    void updateCell(int index, int newValue) {
        cells[index].getValue().set(newValue);
    }
}
```

Note that it's generally best to avoid mixing generics and arrays, so you're better off using `List<Cell<IntWrapper>>` (the performance difference would be negligible).